# StackExchange Just got better

Tags: discussion, status-norepro, stack-overflow, meta

I just logged in and found that there is a font change in SE sites ( StackOverflow & MetaStackOverflow ). I am using Google Chrome Version 32.0.1700.107. I marked the same font change in Firefox browser as well. Is this new look or Is it temporary ? By the way I like this new look very much.

Comment: Looks the same to me...

Comment: @animuson, Yes normally it looks same but when you edit any post or see any formatted code than it looks different,even in this comment box fonts are different.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian, no I didnt get glasses, no need for them. And I am not joking. You should have notice [comment font change](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2tj1E.png) and [Edit post font change](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NOA9i.png) and [Question with code](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8LZn6.png)

Comment: @animuson, I do not have enough reputation, can you please post my last comment into my question ? It gives better understanding of my question description.

Comment: Did you recently install or remove fonts on your computer? Because nothing has changed in the on-site CSS.

Comment: @animuson, nopes nothing new installation done.

Comment: Welcome, Sir Rip-Van-Winkle. Share a coffee

Comment: "SE got better!" no repro. *d'oh!*

Comment: @Shog9, In previous years when I used to update my windows, that time during the installation in one screen it shows a screen "Windows Just got better", That why I use this title.

Comment: "*Stand by, we're improving your Stack Exchange Experience*" - I think that could be the makings of a great April 1 gag :)

Comment: @TimPost: It's getting close to that time of year!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We uh, haven't made any changes lately. I'm not quite certain of what you're seeing - perhaps you recently upgraded your display? (Retina makes a world of difference in fonts) .. ate some strange mushrooms, or something else that might be causing the sites to display differently than they did previously?

No changes to CSS have been pushed in the recent past, so I'm a little baffled as to what might be causing you to see things differently. I looked at the screen shots you provided, but the things you've pictured have looked the way that they do for quite a while.

I wish I could be more help, but .. nothing accounts for what you're reporting :)

Comment: Yes you are right. I just check this with my colleague, On his computer it is showing normal. Looks like something updated automatically on my computer. But yes this is new look on my computer. Thanks for clearing doubt.

Comment: @user3322955 If you figure out what updated, can you drop a comment here? I'm really curious as to what might be causing such a stark difference in how fonts appear.

Answer (score 4):

Its mistake from my side. I just remind that yesterday there was a performance issue on my computer. Due to this my administrator did changes in my computer. He just open on mycomputer's property window -> Performance Option, modified existing option. I believe due to this I am seeing these changes in my browsers.

I apologize for this.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhh, desktop effects. Mystery solved!

Comment: I am now feeling very stupid by asking this question. This question waste around 1 hour of your time too.

Comment: Aww, don't - this was a little unexpected mystery in an otherwise kind of dull day, a little funny and now we've identified another way folks might start seeing the site differently but not be certain as to why. It's all good.